# Symbolic link does not work in Git over Windows

Tags: windows, git, symbolic-link

I have a repo called `Base` and another repo called `Project`. They are cloned in `C:\Company\Base` and `C:\Company\Project`.

I use `mklink C:\Copmany\Project\BuildScript.bat C:\Company\Base\BuildScript.bat` to create a symbolic link.

Then I push this change:

```
   cd C:\Company\Project
   git add .
   git commit -m "adding symbolic link"
   git push
```

And I can see in GitHub that the `BuildScript.bat` is a symbolic link.

I can also verify it using `dir /AL /S C:\Company\Project`.

However, when I clone this repository on another PC, or in another directory on my own PC, that symbolic link is not a link anymore.

What should I do?

Comment: Do not use symbolic links at all, especially not outside the repository. If you *must* use the same file, maybe investigate Git submodules.

Comment: @DanielB, may I ask why you emphasis on not using symbolic links at all? We're using them all over our Linux infrastructure for years and they work perfectly.

Comment: Maybe my text came out wrong. I'm specifically talking about symlinks inside a Git repository. They are not portable. A link inside the repository pointing to a file outside the repository is even less portable.

Comment: @DanielB, and we're also using symbolic links inside our git repositories and everything works just fine.

Answer (score 9):

I have similar issue with repository with submodules on the Windows host system (then project deployed on the docker containers, one of the container fail to start).
To check if you haven't enabled correct symlink support:

```
git config --get core.symlinks
```

should return `true`.
If it is not true, then you have to remove and clone you repo one more time with command:

```
git clone -c core.symlinks=true <repository_url>
```

*Note: maybe it possible just to enable it with `git config --set __`, but it was not working for me by some reason*

*Note 2: you also might want to use `--recurse-submodules` if it is repository with sybmodules.*

And there is also possibility to enable symlink support during git installation (it will take global effect).
[Git installation step with symlin option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doUmZ.png)

Comment: Setting `core.symlinks` to `true` within the git config worked for me. No need to remove/clone repo